# Why I Can't delete any objects or file From Assets.xcassets folder in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In Xcode when I add something in Assets.xcassets folder, I can't delete That Thing(Image, AppIcon....) anymore. For example, I want to remove This image that name is Dreams V1 but after I Delete it Xcode gives me an error: couldn't be moved to the trash[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYI24.png)

Comment: Can you go in your project folder in finder and erase or take it out manually?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 11.6 you might get this error when you want to delete some file in Assets.xcassets directly from Xcode.
the solution is: memorize the file's name that you want to delete it -> go to your project file from finder -> go to Assets.xcassets Folder -> and delete that file manually.

Comment: that was a valid strategy also before Xcode 11.6. Glad you found out it still solves to trouble